# How to turn completions on and off in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

Completions are useful but sometimes they get in the way. Is there any way to turn them on and off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box in your screen capture shows the Sublime Text **completions** feature.

To turn *completions* off set the `auto_complete` setting to `false` in your user `Preferences.sublime-settings` file. The user settings file can be accessed from the menu with `Preferences --> Settings`, edit the file in the right column of the window that opens. Just add this line:

```json
"auto_complete": false,
```

There are lots of settings related to the *completions* feature. Here is a list:

```json
// Enable auto complete to be triggered automatically when typing.
"auto_complete": true,

// The maximum file size where auto complete will be automatically triggered.
"auto_complete_size_limit": 4194304,

// The delay, in ms, before the auto complete window is shown after typing
"auto_complete_delay": 50,

// Controls what scopes auto complete will be triggered in
"auto_complete_selector": "meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin, source - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc",

// Additional situations to trigger auto complete
"auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "text.html", "characters": "<"} ],

// By default, auto complete will commit the current completion on enter.
// This setting can be used to make it complete on tab instead.
// Completing on tab is generally a superior option, as it removes
// ambiguity between committing the completion and inserting a newline.
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,

// Controls if auto complete is shown when snippet fields are active.
// Only relevant if auto_complete_commit_on_tab is true.
"auto_complete_with_fields": false,

// Controls what happens when pressing the up key while the first item in
// the auto complete window is selected: if false, the window is hidden,
// otherwise the last item in the window is selected. Likewise for the
// down key when the last item is selected.
"auto_complete_cycle": false,

// When enabled, pressing tab will insert the best matching completion.
// When disabled, tab will only trigger snippets or insert a tab.
// Shift+tab can be used to insert an explicit tab when tab_completion is
// enabled.
"tab_completion": true,
```

You could set up a key binding to toggle the setting on and off like this:

```json
// Change the keys to whatever you want.
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "toggle_setting", "args": {"setting": "auto_complete"} },
```

Note that the `toggle_setting` command will not change the value in the `Preferences.sublime-settings` file just its value in memory.

You could also set *syntax specific* or *project specific* settings as to whether to have `auto_complete` on by default.

Comment: Thank for you answer! Is there any way to set up a hotkey to enable/disable all this?